# Photoshop Script does not change the color anymore

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photo, photos, photoshop-script

This script should change the background color. Until 10 minutes ago that worked too. I have not changed anything on the script and even the backup copy of the script shows no other efect. So there must be an mistake in the script, which is efect by the settings. Has anybody a idea?

**Thanks for your efforts**

```js
var srcDoc = app.activeDocument;
var color = app.backgroundColor;

var l = srcDoc.width.value;
var h = srcDoc.height.value;

if (l/h >16/9)
{
  color.rgb.red = 255;
  color.rgb.green = 255;
  color.rgb.blue = 255;
  app.backgroundColor = color;
  app.activeDocument.resizeCanvas(l, l/(16/9), AnchorPosition.MIDDLECENTER);
}
```

Comment: Could you give an example when it doesn't work? What do you expect vs what it does. Because it only changes the background color when the l/h condition is met.

Answer (score 0):

Try being more explicit in the logic of your if statement, like you are in your resizeCanvas function call. It might be that the steps are executing out of order and the condition is never met.

```js
var srcDoc = app.activeDocument;
var color = app.backgroundColor;

var l = srcDoc.width.value;
var h = srcDoc.height.value;

if (l/h > (16/9) )
{
  color.rgb.red = 255;
  color.rgb.green = 255;
  color.rgb.blue = 255;
  app.backgroundColor = color;
  app.activeDocument.resizeCanvas(l, l/(16/9), AnchorPosition.MIDDLECENTER);
}
```

Comment: Even if I make the change from the If neme, that does not change anything. : C
And I see if the If was used on the basis of the new image size. So I should be sure that the code should have been executed.